# Is there a way to instantly cool down Greater Powers in a place where I can't wait?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> Each Greater Power can only be used once per game day.

http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Powers#Greater_Powers

Game time scale is 20 times faster than real time, so a day is 24 hours divided by 20 = 1.25 hours of real-time to recharge a Greater Power. https://www.youtube.com/v/JaAd8OuwwPk&autoplay=1&start=25&end=27 I don't want to use "sgtm" because it makes physics wonky and I'm in a location where I can't wait (Helgen escape).

So, is there a way—even via exploit, console command, or mod—to cleanly instantaneously cool down a Greater Power? Alternatively, is there a way to be able to use the wait option during the Helgen escape?

Comment: Wait for 24 hours? Not that instantaneous but certainly faster than an hour.

Comment: O right, I forgot about mentioning that in the question. I'm in a location where I can't wait.

Answer (score 4):

LFox' '**No [Racial](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/2998/?) / [Standing Stone](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/3078/?) / [Vampire](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/3304/?) / [Werewolf Form](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/2907/?) / [Nightingale](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/2975/?) Power Cooldown**' set of mods should be able to allow the game to do that. (Those mods don't support the Dawnguard and Dragonborn DLC greater powers, though.)

The mod, **[Shouts & Powers Enhanced](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/35560/?)** works with DLC greater powers, but also modifies dragon shout cooldown.

> In this mod, you can shout as much as you want. There's no cooldown on any shouts, or on any powers. Before you could only use a power once a day. Not anymore! There is a 2-3 seconds cooldown on the powers and the shouts.

Comment: The racial powers one isn't working for me (for Voice of the Emperor (Imperial)), though my power was already on cooldown. The comments on it echo me. The "Shouts & Powers Enhanced" mod does not cool down a power that is already on cooldown (i.e. activated on a save where the power is already on cooldown).